# Rails URL Access

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, so please pardon my ignorance. My issue is that I cannot access the Rails project from the browser. I assume it has something to do with the Rails config, but I am having no luck so far.

**State of the Project**

- I have existing logic (controllers, models, migrations, ...).
- If I leave index.html in place, I see the Rails welcome page because it is apparently rendered before Rails tries to parse the URL.
- If I disable index.html, I get the 'Something went wrong' message which is generated by Rails.
- If I have the httpd.conf document root set to 'my.domain.com/public' I get the Rails error, but if I have it set to 'my.domain.com/', I get an error served up by Apache instead. (So that seems to be correctly configured.)
- The error logs show this error: `File does not exist: /var/www/html/my.domain.com/zombies` when I hit the URL.

**My Environment**

- Rails 3.2.6
- Ruby 1.9.3
- Apache 2.2.3
- CentOS

*If it matters, I'm simply following the tutorial at Rails for Zombies 2.*

Thanks in advance!

**Reference**

**zombies_controller.rb**

```
class ZombiesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /zombies
  # GET /zombies.json
  def index
    @zombies = Zombie.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @zombies }
    end
  end

  # GET /zombies/1
  # GET /zombies/1.json
  def show
    @zombie = Zombie.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @zombie }
    end
  end

  # GET /zombies/new
  # GET /zombies/new.json
  def new
    @zombie = Zombie.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @zombie }
    end
  end

  # GET /zombies/1/edit
  def edit
    @zombie = Zombie.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /zombies
  # POST /zombies.json
  def create
    @zombie = Zombie.new(params[:zombie])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @zombie.save
        format.html { redirect_to @zombie, notice: 'Zombie was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @zombie, status: :created, location: @zombie }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @zombie.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /zombies/1
  # PUT /zombies/1.json
  def update
    @zombie = Zombie.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @zombie.update_attributes(params[:zombie])
        format.html { redirect_to @zombie, notice: 'Zombie was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @zombie.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /zombies/1
  # DELETE /zombies/1.json
  def destroy
    @zombie = Zombie.find(params[:id])
    @zombie.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to zombies_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you have your routing setup? and are you using the webrick development server?

Comment: I have the following routes defined; `resources :zombies`, `root :to => 'zombies#index'`. I have tried using WEBrick but it doesn't appear to help, so I have it shutdown now in favor or Apache.

Comment: I have also tried the domain as follows; `http://my.domain.com:3000/zombies` and `http://my.domain.com/zombies`. I get the same result at all times regardless of WEBrick or Apache running.

Comment: You should be using localhost:3000 as the url if you are running it locally.

Comment: It's not local. I've tried using the domain of the development server and also the IP address using the port you indicated. Still nothing. =(

Comment: Can you post your controller code and do you have your views properly set?

Comment: I assume all the views are correct since they were automatically added by the Rails scaffolding.

Comment: Disable index.html and visit page to get that _'Something went wrong'_ message you wrote about. Since it's just a message (not a full error report) I bet you're running it in production mode? See then on a server what's the last error in your `{APP_ROOT}/log/production.log` (may check development.log too).

Comment: Have you installed passenger (this is what helps apache serve ruby apps)? You'll make life a lot easier if you develop locally rather than on some remote server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `rake assets:precompile` seems to have fixed my issue. Thanks all.